# Symfony2 Knp-snappy to generate PDF from a twig view that contain heicharts

Tags: symfony, pdf

I want to generate a PDF file from a twig view that contains heighcharts 
the heighcharts are  not displayed in the pdf file.
why ? any suggestions

```
$html = $this->render('AcmequizBundle:Resultat:show.html.twig', array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'chart'=>$ob
        ));


return new Response(
    $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html,array('encoding'=>'UTF-8','enable-javascript' => true,'images' => true)),
    200,
    array(
        'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="Rapport.pdf"'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts is a JS library, it uses client's browser to generate charts. You should generate charts on server side in any image format and include it to your PDF twig template.

Some info about server side charts generation: http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-articles/news/52-serverside-generated-charts